# Increment and decrement button with 'keydown' (ArrowUp and Down)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, addeventlistener

I need some help with a school assignment. I have two buttons, one for increment and one for decrement. I have four functions, where two of them is for clicking and two for pressing arrow keys. Clicking works fine, but to use arrowUp and ArrowDown i need to click and select the button with the mouse once for it to work.  Can i add something to my two lower arrow key functions  so that i dont need to click them once before i can start using arrow keys?

```
let element = document.querySelector('#value')
let buttonIncrease = document.querySelector('#increase')
element.textContent = '1'
let buttonDecrease = document.querySelector('#decrease')
buttonDecrease.disabled = true;

//Increment number by 1 on click
buttonIncrease.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) + 1
  if (element.textContent > 1) {
    buttonDecrease.disabled = false;
  }
})

//Decrement number by 1 on click
buttonDecrease.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
  if (element.textContent < 2) {
    buttonDecrease.disabled = true;
  }
})

//Increment number by 1 on keydown
buttonIncrease.addEventListener('keydown', (up) => {
  if (up.key === 'ArrowUp' ) {
    element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) + 1
  }
  if (element.textContent > 1) {
    buttonDecrease.disabled = false;
  }
})

//Decrement number by 1 on keydown
buttonDecrease.addEventListener('keydown', (down) => {
  document.getElementById('decrease')
  if (down.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
  }
  if (element.textContent < 2) {
    buttonDecrease.disabled = true;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to define muse click on increment and decrement buttons

> but to use arrowUp and ArrowDown i need to click and select the button
> with the mouse once for it to work.

you can detect whene arrowUp and arrowDown clicked by add event lisner directly to keyboard:

`addEventListener("keydown", function (e) { // Do something }`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can attach the `keydown` event handler to the `window`, so that no matter what element in the DOM has focus, so long as the event can bubble to the `window` element, the value will be changed.

Also note that you can combine the `keydown` event handlers in to one, and you can also make the code more succinct and DRY by extracting the repeated logic in to functions:

```js
let buttonIncrease = document.querySelector('#increase');
let buttonDecrease = document.querySelector('#decrease');
let element = document.querySelector('#value');

buttonDecrease.disabled = true;
element.textContent = '1';

const setButtonState = () => buttonDecrease.disabled = parseInt(element.textContent, 10) <= 1;
const updateValue = increment => {
  value.textContent = Math.max(1, Number(element.textContent) + increment);
  setButtonState();
}

buttonIncrease.addEventListener('click', () => updateValue(1))
buttonDecrease.addEventListener('click', () => updateValue(-1))

window.document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let value = Number(element.textContent);
  let increment = e.key === 'ArrowUp' ? 1 : e.key === 'ArrowDown' ? -1 : 0;
  updateValue(increment);
})
```

```css
#value {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button id="decrease">-</button>
<span id="value">1</span>
<button id="increase">+</button>
```